# The correct way of implementing SSL on localhost

Tags: openssl, nginx, ssl, certificates

Could anyone suggest a modern way of generating self-signed certificates to be implemented on localhost, which would be accepted by Chrome and Mozilla?

I tried the openssl generation, however Mozilla complains that the issuer is untrusted.

Centos 7, nginx

Comment: Use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: It's local domain, Let's encrypt works only on registered

Comment: Firefox says 'It's not certificate authority certificate' when I add the certificate

Comment: Navigate to the site, click advanced, and click add exception.

Comment: @RichardSmith It's not a solution, the site will be shown as 'Unsecure'

Comment: You want it to appear secure, you will need a self-signed CA and use it to sign your server's certificate, then you can add the CA to the browser's trust store.

Comment: Could you please write in Answer form the procedure or at least a link for doing that?

Comment: It seems that Firefox has stopped accepting self-signed certificates. As @RichardSmith says, you'll need to use a Certification Authority to generate your certificates.  Before you dive into that minefield, you may need to study the security implications of operating your own Authority.

Comment: `Before you dive into that minefield, you may need to study the security implications of operating your own Authority.` 

This is an answer....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Warning: Before you dive into the minefield of running your own Certification Authority, you may need to study the security implications!**

But if you must, read on for a quick and dirty CA that will give you `https://localhost/` without a warning message...

Create the following text file:

```
# OpenSSL configuration for Root CA

[ req ]

prompt             = no
string_mask        = default

# The size of the keys in bits:
default_bits       = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions    = x509_ext

[ req_distinguished_name ]

# Note that the following are in 'reverse order' to what you'd expect to see.

countryName = gb
organizationName = Test
commonName = Test Root CA

[ x509_ext ]

basicConstraints=critical,CA:true,pathlen:0
keyUsage=critical,keyCertSign,cRLSign
```

Save as `root.cnf` then generate the request with:

```
$ openssl req -x509 -new -keyout root.key -out root.cer -config root.cnf
```

This will create your Root CA certificate (`root.cer`) and your Root CA private key (`root.key`) which you must keep private.  It will prompt for a password for the private key - ensure you choose a strong one.

Now create a config file for the server certificate:

```
# OpenSSL configuration for end-entity cert

[ req ]

prompt             = no
string_mask        = default

# The size of the keys in bits:
default_bits       = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

x509_extensions    = x509_ext

[ req_distinguished_name ]

# Note that the following are in 'reverse order' to what you'd expect to see.

countryName = gb
organizationName = Test
commonName = localhost

[ x509_ext ]

keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature,keyAgreement

subjectAltName = @alt_names

# Multiple Alternate Names are possible
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
# DNS.2 = altName.example.com
```

Save it as `server.cnf` and generate the request with:

```
openssl req -nodes -new -keyout server.key -out server.csr -config server.cnf
```

The above will generate another private key (`server.key`) which you must protect.  In this case, the key is not password protected, but you may add a password by removing the `-nodes` option.

Finally, sign the request with your new Root CA and extensions from the `server.cnf` file (for convenience):

```
$ openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA root.cer -CAkey root.key -set_serial 123 -out server.cer -extfile server.cnf -extensions x509_ext
```

Note: pick any random number for the `-set_serial` option.

It will ask for the password you entered when you generated the Root CA.

A server certificate (`server.cer`) will be generated.

Now, add the Root CA certificate (`root.cer`) to Firefox's trust-anchor store so that the browser trusts your new CA.

Run a test by using OpenSSL as a temporary web-server with:

```
$ sudo openssl s_server -key server.key -cert server.cer -accept 443 -www
```

Note: You may get errors if you already have a sever running on port 443. In which case, either stop the running server or change the port number above to another unused port by changing the ending to (for example) `-accept 8443 -www`

When you naviate to `https://localhost` (or `https://localhost:8443` if you changed the port number above) with Firefox, you should now see no warning and be presented with a list of ciphers your installation of OpenSSL can offer.

Once you're happy with the results, add the `server.key` and `server.cer` to your original webserver and configure accordingly.

Comment: There's a typo; `stinguished_name` should be `distinguished_name`

Comment: you say: (or https://localhost:<port> if you changed the port number above)... where can i set the port number?

Comment: ok, sorry, then i did not correctly understand the final part of your explanations. anyway, i could add the root certificate through the firefox  preferences and now it works correctly.

Comment: my issue is: what does "sudo openssl ... -accept 443 -www"? does it open a browser? just check if it can correctly access localhost on port 443? it's close to "add root CA to firefox" so it was not clear to me if it would add the certificate or just test it. (i did took notes on my process, but i don't know how to share them... 80% of it is your reply, so i won't post it as an answer in here : - )

Comment: i wonder why you're testing it with openssl and not with firefox directly... but, yes, if that is your goal, than it's better.

Comment: @a.l.e - Because `opnessl` provides the a quick server for testing the certificates, while Firefox provides the client.  You can skip running `openssl` as a server if you wish and add the new certs/key to your main server; but if it doesn't work you won't know if the issue is this configuration of the main server, or the generation of the certificates, or the configuration of Firefox's trust-anchor store!

Comment: ok, i think i got it now. what about first getting the reader to test with openssl and then add the certificate to firefox? (the next step being to test the https localhost.)

Comment: @a.l.e - because the reader can't test with Firefox until the certificate is added to Firefox :-)